# get vars in a function in web routes LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a function to send emails to users.

```
Route::get('sendmail/{mensaje}/{email}', function(){
$data=array(
    'mensaje' => $_GET("mensaje")
);

Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message){
$message->from('exampleemail12@gmail.com', 'Felicidades Por Tu Adopción!');
$message->to('exampleemail12@gmail.com')->subject('Felicidades Por Tu Adopción');
});
});
```

I am sending some vars to that routed via ajax. The problem is that I don't know how can I get those vars passed.

I am using $_GET but it doesn't seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters as arguments of your function:

```
Route::get('sendmail/{mensaje}/{email}', function ($mensaje, $email)
{
    $data = array(
        'mensaje' => $mensaje
    );

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->from('exampleemail12@gmail.com', 'Felicidades Por Tu Adopción!');
        $message->to('exampleemail12@gmail.com')->subject('Felicidades Por Tu Adopción');
    });
});
```

You can see more at the doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters

> Sometimes you will need to capture segments of the URI within your
>   route. For example, you may need to capture a user's ID from the URL.
>   You may do so by defining route parameters:
>
> ```
> Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
>     return 'User '.$id; });
> ```
>
> You may define as many route parameters as required by your route:
>
> ```
> Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
>     // 
> });
> ```